# Fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to put an image and label on my navigation bar so I decided to do it like this:

```
class FixedImageNavigationItem: UINavigationItem {

    private let fixedImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "navlogo")!
    private var imagak : UIImageView!
    private let imageView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 129, height: 40))
    private var labelaki : UILabel!


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let tView = imageView
        imagak = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 3, width: 32, height: 35))
        labelaki = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 38, y: 10, width: 87, height: 21))
        imagak.image = fixedImage
        labelaki.text = "Prime Help"
        labelaki.textColor = UIColor.white
        imageView.addSubview(labelaki)
        imageView.addSubview(imagak)
        tView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.titleView = tView

    }


}
```

The above code works great on iphone 5 and later, but when I tried to test it on iphone 4s ios 8 I got this error:

> fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(title:)' for class
>   'Insurance.FixedImageNavigationItem'

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about implementing the initializer?

Comment: 5s is about to be abandoned. Why would you support 4s really?

Comment: @vadian how can I implement it? (I now use it on storyboard in navigation bar custom class)

Comment: iOS8 seems to call it. Use conditional `#available` attribute

Comment: @vadian when I try to use #available it tells me it expects declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with device type but with iOS versions as [init(coder:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624950-init) method was introduced in iOS 9, and hence the crash.

But the initiaizer [init(title:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624943-init), is available to use in iOS versions above iOS 2.0 and you have nit implemented it on iOS 8, which is what the error is stating.

You should implement `init(title:)` instead of `init(coder:)`.

Comment: As I understand I can't use this code for ios 8? (because with title I assume I will have to set only a title) right?

Comment: No, its an init function, you should call its init function and write the same code.

Comment: When i'm doing it I have an error that says me that I have to use init with coder

Comment: Which is correct because initCoder gets called if you design stuff in storyboard. Can you use nib instead and use its awakeFromNib method to design your view

Comment: Hm ok I will try that. And inform you how it goes

Comment: I don't know if you meant that but I deleted my init coder and put the     override func awakeFromNib()  only, and an if available ios 9 and above and my code and it worked..

Comment: I actually didn't have to do the if check it works now for all version only with awakefornib

Comment: @mikevorisis: Yeah thats what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `initWithCoder` only if it the going to be configured in Storyboard or Xib. In your case most of the elements are already declared as constants. When you override, `initWithCoder`, you must also override `initWithTitle` as `initWithTitle` is the designated intializer for `UINavigationItem`. Sample code would like something like this.

```
 class CustomNavItem :UINavigationItem {
    private let fixedImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: "navlogo")!
    private var imagak : UIImageView!
    private let imageView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 129, height: 40))
    private var labelaki : UILabel!

    override init(title: String) {
        super.init(title: title)
        self.configure()

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.configure()
    }
    func configure() {
        let tView = imageView
        imagak = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 3, width: 32, height: 35))
        labelaki = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 38, y: 10, width: 87, height: 21))
        imagak.image = fixedImage
        labelaki.text = title
        labelaki.textColor = UIColor.white
        imageView.addSubview(labelaki)
        imageView.addSubview(imagak)
        tView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.titleView = tView
    }
}
```